# VSCode: keep focus in folders panel after selecting a file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to navigate files in VSCode workspace efficiently via keyboard: exploring the repo by looking at dozens of files before I find a good one.

I can highlight some file in the Folders view by clicking it, then I use arrows to navigate around (so far so good), but when I click `Enter`, the file is opened *and the editor takes focus* - which prevents me from navigating the tree further.

Is it possible to configure VSCode so that editor does not take focus after I open it from the sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT}: **As of v1.38** a new command has been added that allows you to open an explorer file and keep focus in the explorer:

> Open file and preserve focus
>
> Now it is possible to open the file in preview from the explorer while
>   preserving the focus in the explorer. The new command is
>   `filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus` and by default it can be triggered
>   via the `space` key.

from [open file and preserve focus](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_38#_explorer-improvements)

---

[Original answer - now see edit above]

You can do this in one step with a macro extension which enables you to run two commands with the `enter` key.  Here I am using the [multi-command extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) which has an `interval` delay option. A 150ms delay between the commands seems necessary to allow the file to be opened before switching focus back to the file explorer.

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.openFileKeepFocusInExplorer",
    "interval": 150,
    "sequence": [
      "list.select",
      "workbench.explorer.fileView.focus",
    ]
  }
]
```

And then assign a keybinding (in keybindings.json) to that multi-command:

```
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "multiCommand.openFileKeepFocusInExplorer",
  "when": "sideBarFocus && activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.explorer'"
},
```

In the demo below, I am only using the `arrow` and `enter` keys to move between files, open them and keep focus in the file explorer:

[image: file open and keep focus demo]

Comment: Works great. To complement the answer, `Ctrl+1` can be used to focus the editor.

Answer (score 2):

The best I found so far is that it is possible to create a key binding to bring back the focus to explorer: `ctrl-shift-p` > `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` > look for  `workbench.explorer.fileView.focus` (by default there's no key binding assigned).